# Resources linking in Dropwizard / JAX-RS 1.x (JSR 311)

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs, dropwizard

I've got a problem with resources linking in Dropwizard. With JAX-RS 2.0 we've got magical `javax.ws.rs.core.Link` class which with it's builder can do almost all the work for you. Unfortunately **Dropwizard 0.7.1** doesn't depend on the new 2.0 API, but on the old `javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api` API, which can't handle linking. Or can it? This is the problem I want to solve with Dropwizard. I probably have two ways to do it and I don't know if any of them is valid:

- **Option 1**: I add JAX-RS 2.0 dependency to my project. Voila! I've got Link. But the problem is, that it doesn't work well with old implementations from Jersey - I got `AbstractMethodException` from UriBuilder, which apparently changed from version 1 to 2. So the answer is to supply new implementations. **Can I do it? If yes, than how can I do it? Will new implementations work with dropwizard well?**
- **Option 2**: I can just add some other resource linking to dropwizard. Is there some other linking standard/library? I can't use `jersey-declarative-linking` because it mixes representations with the resources (the linking takes place in representations), and I want my representations not to know a thing about resources layer. **So is there another linking standard for Dropwizard, Jersey and JAX-RS 1?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally found an answer to my question.

Option 2 was a dead end. There was no other jax-rs-2-like linking library to either dropwizard or jersey itself.

Option one also was hard to do, but fortunatelly yesterday dropwizard released version **0.8.0-rc1** of their framework, which depends on jersey 2, which is the implementation of JAX-RS 2.0. So for all of you that want to have HATEOAS in dropwizard, version 0.8.0 is for you.